# Store multiple values in Redux Store using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to store multiple values in redux store based on user logged in, I am using below code on my login screen :

I want to store  emp_id(string) and isValidCE(boolean) values to redux store.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as actionTypes from '../../store/action'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';


class Login extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
  username:'',
  password:'',
  }
 }

 async handleClick(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    var username = this.state.username
    var password = this.state.password
    var emp_id = "";
    var isValidCE = false;
    var isValidEmp = false;
    var self = this;

    await UsersApiService.fetchloginData(username)
    .then((res) => {
      let  userInfo = []
      userInfo  =  res.data

      console.log(res.data)
      if (userInfo === null)
      {
        alert("Username or password is incorrect")
      }
      else if(userInfo['password'] === password){
          console.log("Login successfull");
          console.log(userInfo['validemp'])
          console.log(userInfo['emailid'])
          
          UserApiService.checkUser(username)
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            if(res.data.length > 0)
            {
              //console.log(res.data[0]['emp_id'])

              isValidCE = true 

              emp_id = res.data[0]['emp_id']

              this.props.onEMPPass(emp_id)
              this.props.onValidEMPPass(isValidCE)
              
            }
            console.log('Valid user'+isValidCE)
            var uploadScreen=[];

            uploadScreen.push(<UploadScreen appContext={self.props.appContext}  
            emp_id = {emp_id}  
            isValidEmp = {userInfo['validemp']}  
            isValidCE = {isValidCE}
            emaliid = {userInfo['emailid']}/>)

            
            console.log('new tid  '+this.props.tid)
            console.log('new susr  '+this.props.susr)

            self.props.parentContext.setState({loginPage:[],uploadScreen:uploadScreen})

          });
        }
        else 
        {
          alert("Username or password is incorrect.")
        }
       
    })
    .catch(console.log)
    }
    

render() {
    return (
      <div> 
        <MuiThemeProvider>
          <div >
         {/* 
         <AppBar position ="static" style ={loginStyle} title="Login">
          </AppBar>
         */} 
        <AppBar position='static' style ={loginStyle}>
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography variant="h6" style = {title}>
              Log In
            </Typography>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>

           <TextField 
             hintText="Enter your Username"
             floatingLabelText="Username"
             onChange = {(event,newValue) => this.setState({username:newValue})}
             />
            <br/>
             <TextField
               type="password"
               hintText="Enter your Password"
               floatingLabelText="Password"
               onChange = {(event,newValue) => this.setState({password:newValue})}
               />
             <br/>
             <RaisedButton  color="inherit" 
             label="Submit" 
             primary ={false} 
             style={style} 
             onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)}/>
         </div>
         </MuiThemeProvider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStatetoProps = state => {
    return { 
      tid : state.emp_id,
      susr : state.isValidCE
    };
};


const mapDispatchtoProps = dispatch =>{
    return {         
        onEmpPass: (emp_id) => dispatch({type : actionTypes.EMPID, val : emp_id}),
        onValidEMPPass: (isValidCE) => dispatch({type : actionTypes.VALIDCE, val : isValidCE}) 
    };
}

export default connect(mapStatetoProps,mapDispatchtoProps) (Login);
```

action.js code is :

```
export const EMPID = 'EMPID'
export const VALIDCE = 'VALIDCE'
```

and reducer.js has :

```
import * as actionTypes from './action'

const initialState = {
    emp_id: "",
    isValidCE : false
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    if (action.type === actionTypes.EMPID) {
        return {
            ...state,
             emp_id : action.val
        }
    }
    if (action.type === actionTypes.VALIDCE) {
        return {
            ...state,
            isValidCE : action.val
        }
    }
    return state;
};

export default reducer;
```

I can see emp_id in console.log(this.props.tid)...
but second console is showing undefine .

Comment: Where is your ```mapStateToProps``` function?

Comment: I have edited my code,Please check now.

Comment: This might be because it does not wait for the dispatching on the first action. Then the second value is not updated when it reach the console.log

Comment: Can you Please suggest the alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use 2 dispatches at the same time. result might not be the expected one. Try using only 1.

```
onEmpAction: (emp_id, isValidCE) => dispatch({type : actionTypes.EMPACTION, val : {id: emp_id, isValidCE: isValidCE})
```

Replace this

```
         this.props.onEMPPass(emp_id)
         this.props.onValidEMPPass(isValidCE)
```

with this

```
this.props.onEmpAction(emp_id, isValidCE)
```

and then in your reducer

```
if (action.type === actionTypes.EMPACTION) {
    return {
        ...state,
         emp_id : action.val.id,
         isValidCE : action.val.isValidCE
    }
}
```